# Packet handler , or make class from pointer

Tags: c++, networking

I'm having Network client & server , that can comunicate together. They can send packet to both sides , but i dont know how to do Packet Handling in "right" way.

A few routs for me that i know:

- Array of pre - made classes ( list of them ) . Could use Map for that.
- switch (PacketID) case 1: .... I think that explains itself
- Try to make enum - class like Java has. It would be amost as first solution.

What is best solution for packet handler? What is fastest? What method would be most easy way to code it?

Maybe someone has good example of PacketHandling in C++, beacos i didnt find beside switch.

EDIT:
Switches in C++ are O(1) , so they are fast enought! (only one jump + check)

But , you need to have 1 write packet function , one read function , and one execute function. Too much, isnt it? And you would need 3 diff. cases for all of them.

There is other way to do it (with switch) , that is "easy":

```
#define PACKET_ADDCASE(x,y) case PACKETS::x: x(CASE_ACTION, y);
#define PACKET_CHECKER(x,y) switch(x) { \
    PACKET_ADDCASE(PacketDef, y)\
    PACKET_ADDCASE(PacketPing, y)\
    PACKET_ADDCASE(PacketJoin, y)\
\
    case default: std::cout << "Error! Bad packet ID!"; }

void readPacket(PacketData p)
{
    #define CASE_ACTION ReadPacket
    PACKET_CHECKER(PacketID, p);
}
```

(and dont forget to undef it).

Comment: I would suggest against the `#define` for such simple macro/text replacement. Plain `case XXX:` is much more readable, everyone knows what a `case` is, but for `PACKET_ADDCASE` you have to look it up elsewhere for the actual meaning.

Comment: Look up one line above , yea that would be big problem ;) Btw , i could just name it CCASE , or someting else if its isnt that much of simple to undestend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO unless you are working for plain packet router, you usually do not need special optimization on (de-)packetizer.

For me, I have a base serializer class, and extended class for each packet, like this:

```
switch ( Packet::get_id(buffer, buflen) ) {
case kPacket_Foo: return doPacket_Foo(buffer, buflen);
case kPacket_Bar: return doPacket_Bar(buffer, buflen);
...
}

int doPacket_Foo(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t buflen) {
    PacketFoo p;
    if ( p.read_from(buffer, buflen) < 0 ) return -1;
    printf ("foo = %d\n", p.dummy);
    ...
}
int doPacket_Bar(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t buflen) {
    PacketBar p;
    if ( p.read_from(buffer, buflen) < 0 ) return -1;
    printf ("foo = %d\n", p.bar);
    ...
}
```

With this pattern you easily add new packet, and keep things uniform.

Comment: Googled , and its best way to do it i think... With my define struct - it would be most easy way to do it, and fast too.